# Парсер html

Tags: objective-c, javascript

Добрый день, такой впорос: Как найти вот такую строку через парсер `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://script..js"></script>`

```
 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"script"])
```

Если я делаю так, оно находит только такие скрипты

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      VK.init({apiId: 2707690, onlyWidgets: true});
    </script>
```

Comment: Так проверяйте ещё и значение src-атрибута, например на вхождение `if ([srcAttrValue rangeOfString:@"script.js"].location != NSNotFound) { ... }`

Comment: ок, достаю я этот нужный мне js. как его заблочить или удалить или что с ним сделать, что бы не выполнялся? страница лежит локально

Comment: @divilish, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, по аналогии с этим кодом, вы сможете решить проблему. Это код на С# с использование XPATH.

```
var htmlDocument = this.webBrowser.Document; //Указатель на HTML - документ

        if (htmlDocument != null)//Если документ не пустой
        {
            //ищем все тэги "script", he - это один узел из коллекции узлов
            foreach (HtmlElement he in htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"))
            {
                string srcAttributeValue = he.GetAttribute("src");
                //Если значение атрибута содержит то, что нужно
                if (srcAttributeValue.Contains("https://script..js"))
                {
                    //Пишем значение атрибута в переменную str
                    he.GetAttribute("src", str.ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
```